# Can i sync complete data in firebase before moving to another activity?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use firebase for one of my projects. The issue I am facing is I have 3 database ref node which is used across application, due to frequent internet disconnection I have enabled the firebase sync mode. When you enable sync I do notice the slowness.

is there any way to download all the sync data in one activity ? so i can stop the users till all the content are downloaded into the local memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [addListenerForSingleValueEvent()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#addListenerForSingleValueEvent(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)) to attach listeners to each location in the database that you require to be synchronized.  Only progress to the next activity when each of those listeners are triggered.